# How to insert a element in 2d array in C without losing previous value?What is problem with my program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[4][3],i,j,k,row,col;
    puts("Enter the elemennts");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    puts("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    puts("Enter row and column:");
    scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
    row--; col--;
/**    row-2 col-2*/

    for(i=2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(j=2;j>=0;j--)
        {
                a[i+1][j+1]=a[i][j];
                if(i==row && j==col-1)
                    break;
        }
    }
        a[row][col]=k;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here please help me where I am wrong.

As I want to get output like that sample Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
Enter the number:32
Enter row and column:2 2
1 2 3
4 32 5
6 6 7
8
```

Comment: An array is not best fit if you're looking for "insertion" and "deletion". Just saying.

Comment: One mistake i see is the indexing of rows in first for loop, change 3 to 4 in order to access the 4th line

Comment: I think your sample output is wrong. The 6 is doubled as input and after the insertion the array size is increased. Is that something you want happen?

Comment: you move the value from the cell `a[i][j]` to the cell `a[i+1][j+1]`, this is not correct, see my answer

Comment: @aragon Pehaps you didn't notice that in sample output I gave TWO times 6 in INPUT so it shall remain where will it go ? And in my program array is NOT dynamic so when I write int a[4][3] the memory is allocated so size of array does NOT increase

Answer (score 3):

> What is problem with my program?

Your error is `a[i+1][j+1]=a[i][j];` because the cell just after `i,j` is not `i+1,j+1`

A proposal is :

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define NROW 4
#define NCOL 3

int main()
{
  int a[NROW][NCOL] = { 0};
  int i,j,k,row,col;
  puts("Enter the elements");
  for(i = 0; i<(NROW - 1); ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j<NCOL; ++j) {
      if (scanf("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) {
        puts("invalid value");
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }
  puts("Enter the number:");
  if (scanf("%d", &k) != 1) {
    puts("invalid value");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Enter row (1..%d) and column (1..%d):", NROW - 1, NCOL);
  if ((scanf("%d %d", &row, &col) != 2) ||
      (row < 1) || (row >= NROW) || (col < 1) || (col > NCOL)) {
    puts("invalid value");
    return -1;
  }
  row--;
  col--;

  /* i,j at the new last cell position */
  i = NROW - 1;
  j = 0;

  do {
    int previ, prevj; /* the cell before i,j */

    if (j == 0) {
      previ = i - 1;
      prevj = NCOL - 1;
    }
    else {
      previ = i;
      prevj = j - 1;
    }

    a[i][j] = a[previ][prevj];
    i = previ;
    j = prevj;
  } while ((i != row) || (j != col));

  a[row][col] = k;

  for(i = 0; i < NROW; ++i)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < NCOL; ++j)
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra i.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Enter the elements
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
Enter the number:
32
Enter row (1..3) and column (1..3):
2 2
1 2 3 
4 32 5 
6 6 7 
8 0 0 

/tmp % ./a.out
Enter the elements
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
Enter the number:
32
Enter row (1..3) and column (1..3):
1 2
1 32 2 
3 4 5 
6 6 7 
8 0 0
```

As you can see I also check the validity on the inputs, and use preprocessor definitions *NROW* and *NCOL* to easily change the sizes of the array

Comment: thanks May I know your real name? by the way thanks again for great program.Why is the row-col condition in scanf on line 26  - ->     col>NCOL+1 why +1?

Answer (score 1):

Since a 2D array (aka array of array) is based on consecutive memory, you can simplify the code by using `memmove`.

A function to to insert a value at index r, c can be as simple as:

```
#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 3

void insert_arr(int r, int c, int a[][COLS], int v)
{
  size_t elements_to_move = ROWS * COLS - (r * COLS + c + 1);
  memmove(&a[r][c] + 1, &a[r][c], sizeof(int) * elements_to_move);
  a[r][c] = v;
}
```

Example program:

```
void print_arr(int a[][COLS])
{
  for (int i=0; i<ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; ++j) printf("%4d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int  main()
{
  int a[ROWS][COLS];
  for (int i=0; i<ROWS; ++i)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; ++j) a[i][j] = 10*i + j;
  }

  print_arr(a);
  printf("------------------\n");
  insert_arr(1, 1, a, 9);
  print_arr(a);
}
```

Output:

```
   0    1    2
  10   11   12
  20   21   22
  30   31   32
------------------
   0    1    2
  10    9   11
  12   20   21
  22   30   31
```

Comment: I do not followed that way because I do not remember if the norm explicitly says all the cells are consecutive in memory ... and I was too lazy to check ^^. Of course if this is true to use that property simplifies  the work and gives a better solution.

Comment: @bruno The standard do require consecutive layout. So I think `memmove` is the easy solution. However, I guess your answer is more useful for OP as it tells what OP did wrong. That is... OP may learn more from your answer :-) That's also what the voting says. I just posted this solution as an alternative (that I consider easier).

Comment: Thank you for answering me, and I agree with you in these conditions _memmove_ is easier, then I upvote your answer :-)